# how much extra memory does posix_memalign() take?

Tags: c++, memory-management, posix

I am trying to decide if I should use memalign() over malloc() because aligned memory would make my job easier. I read the GNU documentation here (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html) which mentions that `The function memalign works by allocating a somewhat larger block.` I want to know the exact value for that "somewhat larger block".

Logically thinking the extra memory required should be equal to the the value of alignment required. But I am not sure if there is an optimization over that.

Comment: You could just write a toy program that leaks the memory and then run it under valgrind (or see if `mtrace` works for these calls)

Comment: @Useless: tried the following: void *m; posix_memalign(&m, 512, 1024); and valigrind said that it lost 1024. i tried with different alignments like 8, 16, 32 and different memory sizes like 512, 1024, it said that same. So no extra memory needed?

Comment: @Useless: DrewDormann just confirmed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posix is a *standard*, not a specific set of code, but we can look at libc for an example.

Here's what `posix_memalign()` initially allocates in that implementation.

```
mem = malloc (size + 2 * alignment);
```

With this beautiful ASCII illustration.

```
    /*
      ______________________ TOTAL _________________________
     /                                                      \
    +---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
    |               |                         |              |
    +---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
    \____ INIT ____/ \______ RETURNED _______/ \____ END ___/

   */
```

It then **returns to the heap** the unused storage on either end of the allocation.

This means that fragmentation may get worse, though the heap memory used is the **same amount**.

Comment: why 2*alignment? Shouldn't 1*alignment suffice?

Comment: It must allocate some extra bytes at the end, as well (I think).

Comment: @DrewDormann: so you say that if I need 512 bytes, only 512 bytes will be taken from heap, the side effect being memory fragmentation?

Comment: @aakash Memory fragmentation will be *different* and *possibly worse*.  Otherwise, yes.  Correct.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/musl/latest/source/src/malloc/posix_memalign.c https://elixir.bootlin.com/musl/latest/source/src/malloc/mallocng/aligned_alloc.c#L5 1*alignment should be right